# How to access the source code and/or debug a VSE

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, smalltalk

I have an old Win32 application and I need to inspect its code. This application contains the file "VVM31W.DLL", so it would seem it's a VSE (Visual Smalltalk Enterprise) application. Are there any available tools to inspect VSE executable's code and/or debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task of reverse engineering a VSE executable image may not be actually impossible but I would expect it to be extraordinarily difficult. Before spending the many months of meticulous effort to do this reverse engineering, I would first ask myself how critical it is that I see the source code.  I suspect that virtually any application could be re-implemented more easily than reverse engineering a packaged runtime.

No, there are no tools to help with this.  Yes, it will be very difficult.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I see, if there are no specific tools for the task, it's not feasible (at least not for me, with my non-existent Smalltalk VM knowledge). I guess it's also impossible to debug the application, isn't it? I tried with a generic debugger (W32DASM) and I was unable to follow the execution in the Virtual Machine.

Comment: I've traced through the VM of VSE with the source code, a working Smalltalk environment and a C debugging environment and it's still very hard tracing through execution of the VM.  With no source I'd guess that you don't have a chance.

Comment: You might look for at `change.log`file or `*.SML` files - they would contain smalltalk source code. `SLL`files may also include sources